# How to connect generated link by php-ajax with jquery action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

There is some situation like this:

trollindex.htm:

```
[...]
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("* a.jquery").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "trollcommander.php",
            data: ({command: $(this).attr('command')}),
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=iso-8859-2",
            success: function(result)
            {
                $("div.troll").html(result);
            }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
[...]
<div class="troll">
    //BEGIN result before click a.prepareTrolling:
        <p>You can not be trolled yet.</p>
        <a class="jquery" command="prepareTrolling">Prepare Trolling</p>
    //END result before click a.prepareTrolling;

    //BEGIN result after click a.prepareTrolling and before click on a.trollMeNow:
        <p>Trolling is prepared. Are you ready?</p>
        <a class="jquery" command="trollMeNow">Troll me now!</a>
    //END result after click a.prepareTrolling and before click on a.trollMeNow;

    //BEGIN result after click on a.trollmenow:
        <p>Congratulations! You are successfully trolled!</p>
    //END result after click on a.trollmenow;
</div>
[...]
```

trollcomander.php:

```
<?php
    [...]
    $response = "";
    if(isset($_POST['command']) {
        switch($_POST['command']) {
            case "prepareTrolling":
                $response = prepareTrolling() // "This command works ok";
            break;
            case "trollMeNow":
                $response = trollMeNow() // "This command does not want to work :(";
            break;
            default:
                $response = "Unknown command";
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $response;
?>
```

So, when I click on a.prepareTrolling, everything is ok, but when I want to click at a.trollMeNow, which is generated by prepareTrolling(), the command trollMeNow is not running. I think that jquery connects element a.prepareTrolling with onclick action after load page, but it can not to do that after change div.troll with element a.trollMeNow. How to connect element a.trollMeNow with jquery onclick action?

Comment: Display the code to the function `trollMeNow();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you add the ps dynamically.

Then you will need a slighly different call to your click-listener

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.jquery', function ...)
```

to have it listen to dynamically added elements.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Now, I can be successfully trolled! :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to just do an onclick event on the link. That way you avoid any issues with elements that have loaded afterwards. For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourFunction();">Troll me now!</a>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation:

```
$(".troll").on("click", 'a.jquery',function(){
```

or - if there are more places a link can appear:

```
$("body").on("click", 'a.jquery',function(){
```